# wx.TextCtrl how to restrict going down feature?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have mentioned the code below:

```
   self.output = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", style=wx.TE_RICH2 |
                              wx.TE_MULTILINE |
                              wx.TE_READONLY  |
                              wx.TE_NOHIDESEL |
                              wx.TE_AUTO_URL)
```

**Problem:**

Every time self.output is  updating the data is showing every time last line to the  screen.User can't able to read first line or above lines of the data.

**Need Solution:**

When I am clicking the button it's freeze that line.But data needs update on the screen.If user want see the down data I am providing vertical bar by using this they can see the total data.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, have you added horizontal and vertical scrollbars?

Comment: Yes.I added vertical scroll bar.

Comment: @Chennakesavaraomacherla, ok, so what happen when you try to scroll up or down? Or are you saying that you can't do that?

Comment: No.I can do the scroll up but if any new line updating on gui. That control every time going down.I am getting frustrating to read first lines.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `self.output.SetInsertionPoint(0)`. This will set the position of the text "cursor" to the first character in the widget. Or could you perhaps change the size of self.output?

Comment: I have tried using self.output.SetInsertionPoint(0).problem is when the object updating every time it's going down.I need while updating the object also don't go down.

Comment: Coudn't you use SetInsertionPoint() each time you have updated the Control?